# specify datetime week number format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, memory, format

Does someone know if it is possible to get the week number of a date in uint8 instead of int64 as default?

Now I do:

```
df['sales_week'] = df['sales_date'].dt.week
df.astype({'sales_week': 'uint8'})
```

But, it probably isn't optimal memory-wise, is it?

Is it possible to specify the format when using the .week attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it right away using the `astype` method.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sales_date': ['2019-11-15', '2019-11-16'], 'Z':['abc', 'def']})
df.sales_date = pd.to_datetime(df.sales_date)
df['sales_week'] = df.sales_date.dt.week.astype(pd.np.int8)

df.sales_week
# returns:
0    46
1    46
Name: sales_week, dtype: int8
```

Comment: OP is aware that they can use `astype`, they've said as much in the question. Their concern is waste of memory, and they're right: calling `astype` means that pandas first generates an `int64` column which is then promptly discarded. Hence their question about getting an `int8` directly.